# SharePoint field data got blank after changing column type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list

There is a choice field column in SharePoint List.
I have modified the drop-down type to the checkbox type of choice field.
Then my data in that field got disappeared/blank.
Also, it was not present in Version History.

Is there any solution to get my data back for that field?

Comment: Changing type "dropdown --> checkbox" does not clear data stored in items. Have you tried changing back the type?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you add some codes for the choice column?

I cannot reproduce this issue in my list. If the issue persists when you change type back to drop-down, you need to recreate the choice column again.